# What is name of this distribution and can we have 68–95–99.7 rule for it?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics

I have a distribution like this:

[image]

- What is name of this distribution?
- As you know we have `68–95–99.7` rule in `normal distribution`. Can we have something like this in this distribution?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no easy answer to this question.  There are a multitude of distributions that will resemble the above distribution.  For example, the exponential distribution will look like that or a beta distribution with the right parameters.

Comment: The numbers 68, 95 and 99.7 apply because those are the proportions within 1, 2 and 3 sds of the mean for the normal distribution (note that they don't really apply - except in quite large samples from normal distributions - when you estimate the mean and sd). A new distribution means different numbers. If you're dealing with a skewed distribution like that - even if you knew which one you had - it doesn't necessarily make so much sense to quantify the proportions within 1, 2 and 3 sds of the mean. For example, with the exponential distribution, there's nothing more than 1sd below the mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps it is a Exponential distribution with parameter 10, or a Gamma(1,8) distribution, or a Beta(0.5,2) distribution, or a ..... Hopefully the point is clear.

[image]

Of course once the distribution is chosen you can work backwards to figure out what values of the SD's will give you the 68-95-99.7 rule you want although how useful is that rule for an arbitrary distribution is debatable.

Comment: Dan, I have another question. As you know exponential distribution has a tail. my data range for `x-axes` is from `0 to 1`. I don't want this tail in exponential distribution after `1`. Is any other revised other distribution for that?

Comment: The beta distribution lives between 0 to 1.

Comment: In the case of a heavily skewed distribution like this the whole idea of such a rule is silly.  Moving to the left any fraction of $\sigma$ brings in more of the distribution than moving the same distance to the right.  By the way, that is true whether we are starting at $\mu$, or anyplace else at least that distance above the lower bound on the support.